# setting up subdomain at centmin mod

Tags: centos, dns, bind, domain

I am in need of setting up subdomains in my CentOS using centmin Mod.

This is what I have done so far.

1. Purchase a VPS with `IP address: xxx.xxx.xxx` and `hostname: ns.mydomain.com`
2. Install centmin MOD
3. Add two A record at GoDaddy

`@    xxx.xxx.xxx
ns    xxx.xxx.xxx`

4. Using option (2) at centmin.sh, I set up my domain: `mydomain.com`
5. Amaze that `mydomain.com` is really working, I can change the `index page` by working on `/home/nginx/domains/mydomain.com`

Here comes my problem, According to this: https://community.centminmod.com/threads/add-a-subdomain.1774/ , I just need to add the subdomain like a domain, but yet if I try to add subdomain I keep failing,

I work on option (2) again and put my subdomain `sub.mydomain.com`

But, accessing `sub.mydomain.com` keeps on failing, doe I can see that `/home/nginx/domains/sub.domain.com` has been created.

Did I miss something?
Was there something I should have setup again at GoDaddy?

There is this `then add DNS record for subdomain` that I did not understand? Is setting up via option (2) on centmin.sh enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a DNS A record for sub.mydomain.com to point to server IP like you did for mydomain.com

Getting Started guide step 1 at http://centminmod.com/getstarted.html lists how to setup main hostname's DNS which is basically a subdomain as well so same thing add a DNS A record

Comment: Don't forget to add a AAAA record also when you add an A record. It's 2015, IPv6 is decades old and it's about time it received as much attention as its address-exhausted older sibling! :-)